# Looking for a windows-like font to use in HTML

Tags: html, windows, fonts

I am currently looking for a windows10-like font I can use in HTML and that works on most browsers. I have already looked at a bunch of fonts, but non of them really looks like the original. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want [Segoe UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#Segoe_UI).

[CSSFontStack example](https://www.cssfontstack.com/Segoe-UI)

[FontsGeek example](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Segoe-UI-Regular)

```css
body{
font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>

<p>The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog</p>
```

Comment: Comes close, if not identical. Thanks